# How do I rotate an image from a file with Xamarin on iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uiimage

I have been trying to rotate an image for a couple days now, but the best I get is still a black image.

I suspect it may have something to do with the point I'm rotating around but I'm not sure. I say that because I tried the whole solution proposed [here](http://www.catamount.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=967) and translated in Xamarin terms, but that didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
public void Rotate (string sourceFile, bool isCCW){
  using (UIImage sourceImage = UIImage.FromFile(sourceFile))
  {   
    var sourceSize = sourceImage.Size; 

    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(new CGSize(sourceSize.Height, sourceSize.Width), true, 1.0f); 
    CGContext bitmap = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

    // rotating before DrawImage didn't work, just got the image cropped inside a rotated frame
    // bitmap.RotateCTM((float)(isCCW ? Math.PI / 2 : -Math.PI / 2)); 

    // swapped Width and Height because the image is rotated
    bitmap.DrawImage(new CGRect(0, 0, sourceSize.Height, sourceSize.Width), sourceImage.CGImage);

    // rotating after causes the resulting image to be just black
    bitmap.RotateCTM((float)(isCCW ? Math.PI / 2 : -Math.PI / 2)); 

    var resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

    if (targetFile.ToLower().EndsWith("png"))
        resultImage.AsPNG().Save(sourceFile, true);
    else
        resultImage.AsJPEG().Save(sourceFile, true);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to take a `UIImage`, and then rotate it either 90 clockwise or 90 degrees counter clockwise.  You can actually do this with just a few lines of code:

```
public void RotateImage(ref UIImage imageToRotate, bool isCCW)
{
   var imageRotation = isCCW ? UIImageOrientation.Right : UIImageOrientation.Left;
   imageToRotate = UIImage.FromImage(imageToRotate.CGImage, imageToRotate.CurrentScale, imageRotation);
}
```

We use `UIImage.FromImage()` that accepts 3 parameters.  The first is a `CGImage`, from which we can get from the `UIImage` you're trying to rotate.  The 2nd parameter is the scale of the image.  The 3rd parameter is the important one.  We can rotate it using `UIImageOrientation.Right` (90 degrees CCW) or `UIImageOrientation.Left` (90 degrees CW).  You can check out the Apple documentation for the meaning of the other UIImageOrientation constants:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIImageOrientation

UPDATE:
Note that the code above only changes EXIF flags and calling it twice doesn't rotate the image 180deg.

Add this code to make the result cumulative:

```
UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(new CGSize((float)h, (float)w), true, 1.0f);   
imageToRotate.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, (float)h, (float)w)); 

var resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
imageToRotate = resultImage;
```